# 2 Identical Strings aren't matching in string length PHP

Tags: php, string, query-string

I'm trying to compare information from 2 different types of requests as part of my system to allow permissions to certain pages, but keep running into a string comparison issue that is boggling my mind.

#### Result I'm Getting

```php
string(26) "?type=week&date=2015-08-06" // exploded URI
string(30) "?type=week&date=2015-08-06" // query string
```

#### Exploded URI

```php
$pageReqCheck      = explode("/", urldecode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
$accessPermissions = $pageReqCheck[3];
```

#### Query String

```php
$queryString       = "?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

#### EDIT RESULTS FROM FOR LOOP

Query String

int(63) int(116) int(121) int(112) int(101) int(61) int(119) int(101) int(101) int(107) int(38) int(97) int(109) int(112) int(59) int(100) int(97) int(116) int(101) int(61) int(50) int(48) int(49) int(53) int(45) int(48) int(56) int(45) int(48) int(54)

Exploded URI

int(63) int(116) int(121) int(112) int(101) int(61) int(119) int(101) int(101) int(107) int(38) int(100) int(97) int(116) int(101) int(61) int(50) int(48) int(49) int(53) int(45) int(48) int(56) int(45) int(48) int(54)

#### Edited Different Solution

```
$queryString = html_entity_decode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: Run this for each string, then show us the results: `for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) { var_dump(ord($string[$i])); }` where `$string` is the input.

Comment: sounds like `&` vs `&amp;`

Comment: Added in the Post above @Flosculus

Comment: Looks like @VolkerK is right.  `chr(38) . chr(97) . chr(109) . chr(112) . chr(59)` = `&amp`.

Comment: @VolkerK what is a good way to format either both variables so that they use the & or &amp; specifically?

Comment: "I'm trying to compare information from 2 different types of requests as part of my system to allow permissions to certain pages" - this wouldn't happen to involve some mod_rewrite stuff, would it?

Comment: @VolkerK no.  Just the exploded URI and the query string.  Making sure that the exploded URI does not match the query string.

Comment: In that case I find it strange that QUERY_STRING contains the html entity while RQUEST_URI doesn't. Using html_decode_entites() probably treats a symptom not the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$input = [
    'int(63) int(116) int(121) int(112) int(101) int(61) int(119) int(101) int(101) int(107) int(38) int(97) int(109) int(112) int(59) int(100) int(97) int(116) int(101) int(61) int(50) int(48) int(49) int(53) int(45) int(48) int(56) int(45) int(48) int(54)',
    'int(63) int(116) int(121) int(112) int(101) int(61) int(119) int(101) int(101) int(107) int(38) int(100) int(97) int(116) int(101) int(61) int(50) int(48) int(49) int(53) int(45) int(48) int(56) int(45) int(48) int(54) '
];

foreach($input as $t) {
    preg_match_all('!int\((\d+)\)!', $t, $m);
    foreach( $m[1] as $c ) {
        echo chr($c);
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
?type=week&amp;date=2015-08-06
?type=week&date=2015-08-06
```

(on a console that doesn't interpret html entities).

The string you get via $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] contains a literal `&` while the other contains the html entity `&amp;` which represents the same character.
You probably used a (html) browser as the output medium and therefore didn't see the difference.

Comment: Is there a better way than looping, example a regular expression in php that could preg_replace just the &amp; with the &.  It seems like this is a lot of looping since I would have to loop to get the input and then loop to fix the 2 times to fix the input.

Comment: giving you the checkmark because it worked, but I found an alternate solution that I used. html_entity_decode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']